# Not getting an GPIO output

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, gpiozero

I am trying to light a led with the raspberry pi 3b, but I am failing to get an output.

I connected the LED to physical pin #11: [img][https://i.imgur.com/TYeJc10.jpg[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtKdy.jpg)
And to physical pin #6(ground).

[image]

I tried using both gpiozero and RPi.GPIO:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(17)

led.on()
print('on')
sleep(3)
led.off()
print('off')
```

and

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

ledpin = 11
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(ledpin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    GPIO.output(ledpin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(ledpin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
```

For RPi.GPIO I tried both BOARD and BCM, neither worked.
I used [code]gpio readall[/code] from wiringpi, and it shows output but never a 1.
I also used gpiotest with pigpio which gave no errors:

```
Testing... 
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

I also freshly installed the Raspbian OS.
The LED does work when I connect one end to the 3.3V pin.
I am however able to read input, using the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

switch = 31

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(switch, GPIO.IN)


for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(GPIO.input(switch))
    
GPIO.cleanup()
```

And getting 1/0 as output correctly

Anyone got a clue on how to fix this, I am all out of ideas and so seems google.
Also it is the 2nd Raspberry pi I had this problem with.

Comment: The obvious answer is the LED is connected the wrong way around.  Please ensure you always use a resistor in series with a LED (to prevent it burning out).

Comment: "Anyone got a clue on how to fix this" NO - because we don't know what "this" is or what you have connected. What does "getting 1/0 as output correctly" mean? PS DO NOT post pictures of pin layout - we all know this.